# how to enable ssl_module apache

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp, wampserver, mod-ssl

I'm using WAMP on my PC for a project and I need to enable the ssl_module because I need to send emails through Gmail's SSL SMTP...

I know how to enable it (uncomment or using WAMP interface check/uncheck) but neither of my changes work... even if I restart the server..

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you read that smtp.gmail.com requires TLS or SSL. 
If you enable mod_ssl in your Apache config, your webserver can handle https requests (that is http with SSL encryption). However to send emails you have to use a different protocol like SMTP or IMAP. So mod_ssl won't help.
What programming language do you use for this project, PHP? Then take a look at [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page).

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply... I'm using cakephp (PHP)... I already enable the mod_ssl and I'm not getting any erros on sending the email but nothing comes to my email...

Comment: Mod_ssl is not involved in sending emails. It enables your webserver to understand HTTPS requests coming from your browser. You need the openssl extension for PHP. Check phpinfo() for that. And please show the code you use for mailing.